# Why do I get "net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection" when I try to fetch some images with "net/http"

Tags: http, go, networking

I'm writing a web crawler in Go language to collect images on the Internet. My crawler works most of the time, but it sometimes fails to fetch images somehow.

Here's my snippet:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var client http.Client
    var resp *http.Response

    // var imageUrl = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png"  // It works well
    var imageUrl = "https://precious.jp/mwimgs/b/1/-/img_b1ec6cf54ff3a4260fb77d3d3de918a5275780.jpg"  // It fails

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", imageUrl, nil)
    req.Header.Add("User-Agent", "My Test")

    client.Timeout = 3 * time.Second
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())  // Fails here
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        fmt.Printf("Failure: %d\n", resp.StatusCode)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Success: %d\n", resp.StatusCode)
    }

    fmt.Println("Done")
}
```

My snippet above works for most of the URLs (e.g. "https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png"), but it doesn't work if it tries to fetch URLs such as  "https://precious.jp/mwimgs/b/1/-/img_b1ec6cf54ff3a4260fb77d3d3de918a5275780.jpg". Error message given by calling `err.Error()` is:

> Get
>   https://precious.jp/mwimgs/b/1/-/img_b1ec6cf54ff3a4260fb77d3d3de918a5275780.jpg:
>   net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting
>   headers)"

My Go version is "go1.9.3 darwin/amd64", and I can get the image with my Google Chrome and also with `curl` command, so I don't think I'm blocked by my IP address. Besides that, I've changed the User-Agent to be like real browser but still not luck.

What's wrong with my code? Or is the administrator of `precious.jp` doing some magic to block my access?

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using `https`, you need to create `http.Client` with custom *transport* and configure `TLS` (see [http.Transport](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport)), e.g.

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    //---------------------- Modification ----------------------
    //Configure TLS, etc.
    tr := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
            InsecureSkipVerify: true,
        },
    }
    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: tr,
        Timeout:   3 * time.Second,
    }
    //---------------------- End of Modification ----------------

    // var imageUrl = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png"  // It works well
    var imageUrl = "https://precious.jp/mwimgs/b/1/-/img_b1ec6cf54ff3a4260fb77d3d3de918a5275780.jpg" // It fails

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", imageUrl, nil)
    req.Header.Add("User-Agent", "My Test")

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error()) // Fails here
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        fmt.Printf("Failure: %d\n", resp.StatusCode)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Success: %d\n", resp.StatusCode)
    }

    fmt.Println("Done")
}
```

Comment: Thanks! By the way, `i.stack.imgur.com` is also `https`. Why does the domain work without `TLSClientConfig`? I've investigated SSL/TLS certificate info with https://cryptoreport.websecurity.symantec.com/checker/ , but I couldn't find anything doubtful with `precious.jp`

Comment: I'm not sure what was the cause, but when inspecting the request (using `curl -v <IMG_URL>`), the `content-length` header was not set in the response from `precious.jp`. BTW, is the solution in the answer works for your case? I've tested it in my machine, and it was working.

Comment: Yeah, it works on my end as well. Thanks! I'm still wondering if `InsecureSkipVerify: true` is a good idea or not in this scenario though. By the way, I can see `Content-Length` of `precious.jp` actually.